# Scala Worksheet throwing error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am getting an error while running my Scala Code on IntelliJ (using Scala 2.11.8):

```
package week4

/**
  * Created by BigB on 15/08/17.
  */
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}

class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}

class Nil[T] extends List[T] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true

  override def head: T = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")

  override def tail: List[T] =throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
}
```

My Scala Worksheet has:

```
import week4._

object nth {
  def nth[T](n: T, l: List[T]): T = {
    if (l.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    else if (n==0) l.head
    else nth(n-1, l.tail)
  }

  val l1 = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(2, new Nil)))

  nth(2, l1)
}
```

**Errors:**

Error:(9, 20) not found: type Cons
lazy val l1 = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(2, new Nil)))
                  ^

Error:(6, 16) value - is not a member of type parameter T
    else nth(n-1, l.tail)
              ^

Comment: You have to first compile week4 package, then try to run worksheet. At-least it works for me without any code change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nth` is parameterized with `T`. Inside it you call it recursively with `nth(n-1, ...)`.

What's the type of `n-1`? `n` is of type `T`, `1` is of type `Int` the resulting type cannot be inferred to be of type `T` so it fails.

I suggest passing an extra parameter, perhaps:

```
object nth {
  def nth[T](n: T, l: List[T], dec: T => T): T = {
    if (l.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    else if (n==0) l.head
    else nth[T](dec(n), l.tail, dec)
  }

  val l1 = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(2, new Nil)))

  nth[Int](2, l1, _ - 1)
}
```

## Edit

Putting my version of your code in a class that `extends App` works as expected. I've given up using worksheets. Too unreliable or too many hidden secrets.

## Edit no.2

Right clicked the worksheet pressed `Recompile <ws>.sc` and `Run`.sc` and it worked... Oh well worksheets!

[image]

Comment: Even on changing `T` to `Int`, there is a red on `-` sign.. This should be a different issue.

Comment: You're right. Need to explicitly parameterize things :)